# Python regex extracting substrings containing numbers and letters

Tags: python, regex, string

I am attempting to extract a substring that contains numbers and letters:

```
string = "LINE     : 11m56.95s CPU    13m31.14s TODAY"
```

I only want 11m56.95s and 13m31.14s

I have tried doing this:

```
re.findall('\d+', string)
```

that doesn't give me what I want, I also tried this:

```
re.findall('\d{2}[m]+\d[.]+\d|\+)
```

that did not work either, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Regex pattern is not formed correctly.  It is currently matching:

```
\d{2}  # Two digits
[m]+   # One or more m characters
\d     # A digit
[.]+   # One or more . characters
\d|\+  # A digit or +
```

Instead, you should use:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "LINE     : 11m56.95s CPU    13m31.14s TODAY"
>>> re.findall('\d+m\d+\.\d+s', string)
['11m56.95s', '13m31.14s']
>>>
```

Below is an explanation of what the new pattern matches:

```
\d+  # One or more digits
m    # m
\d+  # One or more digits
\.   # .
\d+  # One or more digits
s    # s
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation makes much more sense, How do I print the results without having the brackets around the regular expression I am extracting?

Comment: @octain - The brackets mean that the output is a list.  You could remove them by using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): `print ', '.join(re.findall('\d+m\d+\.\d+s', string))`.  Of course, that is just an example; it depends on what output you want.

Comment: I want to write the output to a file i did something like this: `l = re.sub(r'\d+m\d+\.\d+s', line)` and `wd0.write(str(l))`

Comment: Well, `re.sub` is used to replace patterns in a string.  You want to do something like: `for match in re.findall('\d+m\d+\.\d+s', string): wd0.write(match + '\n')`

Comment: I tried playing around with the other regex tools,  I will give that a try thanks again!

Comment: It worked fine. I attempted doing something else Idk either it's different with regex or I am doing it wrong. I have `for num in re.findall(r'\d{1}\.\d{1}', string): sum =0 sum += float(num) print(num)` I am trying to sum up all the numbers I found, the print gives me the list of numbers with no sum, I made sure my print(num) is outside the for loop also tried print(sum) but still lists the numbers found by regex

Answer (score 3):

Your current regular expression does not match what you expect it to.

You could use the following regular expression to extract those substrings.

```
re.findall(r'\d+m\d+\.\d+s', string)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cJ9cL4/2)

**Example**:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'LINE     : 11m56.95s CPU    13m31.14s TODAY'
>>> for x in re.findall(r'\d+m\d+\.\d+s', s):
...     print x

11m56.95s
13m31.14s
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
re.findall("[0-9]{2}[m][0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}[s]", string)
```

Output:

```
['11m56.95s', '13m31.14s']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\b   #word boundary
\d+  #starts with digit
.*?   #anything (non-greedy so its the smallest possible match)
s    #ends with s
\b   #word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lines are all like your example split will work:

```
s = "LINE     : 11m56.95s CPU    13m31.14s TODAY"

spl = s.split()

a,b = spl[2],spl[4]
print(a,b)
('11m56.95s', '13m31.14s')
```